# Need xpath to locate button whose id is dynamic how to click that using in RobotFramework automation script

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

Following is the code which will give me a '+' symbol on clicking it a popup window will appear, I tried xpath to locate this but it didn't work someone please help me to figure out this issue.

I am using Robot framework

```html
<div id="button-1571" class="x-btn x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-icon x-btn-icon x-btn-default-toolbar-small-icon" style="border-width: 1px; left: 373px; margin: 0px; top: 6px;">

    <em id="button-1571-btnWrap">
        <button id="button-1571-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" autocomplete="off" role="button" hidefocus="true" type="button" style="height: 16px;">
            <span id="button-1571-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner" style="margin: -1px 0px;"></span>
            <span id="button-1571-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon icon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </em>

</div>
```

This is the code which i tried
Click Button    xpath=//div[contains(@class, 'x-btn x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-icon x-btn-icon x-btn-default-toolbar-small-icon')]/descendant::button[contains(@class, 'x-btn-center')]/span[contains(@class, 'x-btn-icon icon-plus')]

Comment: Please use xpath : //*[@id="button-1571-btnEl"]

Comment: I tried that also but it didnt work....the error is element didnt appear...can u pls suggest some other solution.

Comment: Use in this way : By.xpath("//*[@id='button-1571-btnEl'] "   I have done little change. in Quotes.

Comment: @HelpingHands: The title says that the button's ID is dynamic.

Comment: @LarsH - Yes but xpath helps to find dynamic value/Element , right?

Comment: @HelpingHands Thanks for the input, Sorry i forgot to mention about RobotFramework can you please suggest how to use in that

Comment: Can you specify your question in more better way ?

Comment: @KUMARRAJA - that is diff. question. Please update your question with proper detail.

Comment: @HelpingHands I am using Robot framework, I am using Click Button xpath=//div[@id='button-1571']/descendant::button[contains(@class, 'x-btn-center')]/span[contains(@class, 'x-btn-icon icon-plus')]

On clicking this button i will get a popup

Answer (score 0):

Please put another question for RobotFramework issue. 
About the question to locate the Web-element you can use below Xpath, It will work for you.

Below code will click on the Web-Element.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-btn x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-icon x-btn-icon x-btn-default-toolbar-small-icon']/em/button/span[@class='x-btn-icon icon-plus']"))).click();
```